# select each id by number in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Need to get id's as numbers

```
<div class="user-view">

<div class="show_user_div">

<div class="disp">
<a href="/profile/name1/">name1</a><br />
<span id="show_a_3">
<a id="ref_show(3)">Show Details</a>
</span></div><div id="user_col_3"></div></div>
<div class="disp">
<a href="/profile/name2/">name2</a>
<br /><span id="show_a_4">
<a id="ref_show(4)">Show Details</a>
</span>
</div>
<div id="show_user(4)"></div>

</div>
```

in js code i'm trying to select each number by **(i)** variable.

```
$('#user_show(i)').on('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "display",
        data: {'id':i},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("show_user_"+i).innerHTML=data;
            document.getElementById("show_a_"+i).innerHTML="<a 
            onclick=setTimeout('hide_user("+i+")',500)>Hide</a>";
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
});
});
```

but it's not working i receive error

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #show_user(i)
```

How can i take the numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should apply a class to all of the tags you want to include, then tie your onclick event to the class instead of using a variable in the ID.

If you need to pull a unique value from each a-tag, you can add a data- element to it instead of trying to pack that info into the id.

```
<a id="show_user_4" class="ref_show" data-val="4" >Show Details</a>
```

Then for your ajax:

```
$('.ref_show').on('click', function(){
    var clickedId = $(this).attr('data-val')
    $.ajax({
        url: "display",
        data: {'id': clickedId},
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("show_user_"+data.i).innerHTML=data;
            document.getElementById("show_a_"+i).innerHTML="<a 
            onclick=setTimeout('hide_user("+i+")',500)>Hide</a>";
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Error!');
        }
});
});
```

Comment: Sorry I just copy-pasted your success function but that would have to be changed as well. Pass i from your view and then reference it as data.i.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. It clicked successfuly for only on one click on top button, but others are inactive. Then id is not providing to controller. 
Success function it's not neccesary now, cause im geting error before =(

Comment: Can you post your updated html? Also, when you say inactive, you mean that you click and the ajax request doesn't fire?

Comment: now i tried once more and renamed id's to class like you said. And now all buttons active. But anyway i get error alert cause id's didn't post to controller.

Comment: "Missing required parameters: id"

in my controller code i have this action

public function actionDisplay($id)
{ 

 if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {

  
  return $id;
 
 }
}

in ajax succes function i have :

success: function(data){
   alert(data);
  },

Comment: It may be expecting the variable named "$id" and you are passing it "id". Try chainging the ajax data option to read: data: {'$id': clickedId},

Comment: I should add that if your only use of the id is to put it in the success function, you can probably just replace "data.i" with clickedId and not pass it as data at all. If you need to use it on the controller side then you'll have to pass it and figure out that issue.

Comment: Thanks, i have rewrited my code from POST to GET and it works well. 
[code]$.get('display', {'id':clickedId}, function(data){[code]

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue you're having is you're trying to find an element with the ID `show_user(i)` instead of `show_user(the actual ID)`. Try replacing `i` in the string with i as a variable, like so

```
$('#show_user(i)'.replace('i', i)).on('click', function() {
  // ...
});
```

Comment: sorry, yes i had a mistake with show_user. i edited just now. then i tried your code. 
i receiving this error - "Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined"

Comment: where are you declaring the variable i? are you doing this in a for loop, such as for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++)? uncaught reference errors have to do with when a variable isn't defined at all, which is what i'm guessing the issue you're having is

Comment: guess, nowhere i think. will try to declare variable for i.